# How can I calculate the angle to the horizontal axis of a reflected ray from a rotated line?

Tags: c++, math, game-physics

I’m having a C++ program and i want to calculate the reflection angle for a light ray. In the example, I have a yellow line(light ray) with an angle of 135 degrees to the X-Coordinate that hits the red line from which it should be reflected. The green line is the reflected line. I have already tried to calculate the angle between the red and the yellow line, but I don’t know what to do with the rotated line. So here is my question: How do I calculate the angle of the green line to the horizontal axis? Code would be nice.

This Code should calculate the angle between the yellow and the red line:

```cpp
float a = atan(abs((HitPointWithRedLine.x - YellowLineStartPoint.x)) / abs(HitPointWithRedLine.y - YellowLineStartPoint.y)) * 180 / 3.14;
```

But because I don’t know what to do with the angle of the line, I tried this (which obviously doesn’t work):

```
float resultAngle = a - angleLine
```

[image: Example]

Soution:

This solution might not be the best but it works. It might be better to use vectors rather then angles for those callculations:

```cpp
    int LineAngle = 0;

    int IncidentAngle = 135;
    int beta = 180 - IncidentAngle;

    int AngleOfRefrection = beta + 2 * LineAngle;


//edge case:
    if (IncidentAngle == 90)
        AngleOfRefrection = 270;
        
    else if (IncidentAngle == 180)
        AngleOfRefrection = 0;

    else if (IncidentAngle == 270)
        AngleOfRefrection = 90;

    else if (IncidentAngle == 360 || IncidentAngle == 0)
        AngleOfRefrection = 180;
```

Comment: Could you add a drawing of what you mean? It's difficult to follow your description. And FWIW, you can do usually achieve what you want in game physics using only vector operations such as dot and cross products, which are often simpler, stabler, and faster.

Comment: I have added an image. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 0: Figure out your coordinate system, which way is zero degrees, which way is 90 degrees, and so on.

Step 1: Generate some test cases

- yellow: 0 degrees, red: 0 degrees
- yellow: 10 degrees, red: 0 degrees
- yellow: 20 degrees, red: 0 degrees
- yellow: 20 degrees, red: 10 degrees

Step 2: Work out by hand what the answers should be.  Here are a few, but you'll want to handle all the corner cases you can think of:

- green: 0 degrees
- green: -10 degrees
- green: -20 degrees
- green: 0 degrees

Step 3: Write some code that gets the right answers

- e.g. Given two points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2), what direction is that?
- Hint: atan() is not enough, have you seen atan2()?

Step 4: Return the result in the correct format.

- As an angle?
- As a pair of x,y coordinates?

Good luck with that assignment!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not calculating the angle between two lines or vectors. Use the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition) for that. I am not exactly sure what your variables mean but if you have two vectors redLine and yellowLine you can use:

```
float lengthRedLine = sqrt(redLine.x * redLine.x + redLine.y * redLine.y) 
float lengthYellowLine = sqrt(yellowLine.x * yellowLine.x + yellowLine.y * yellowLine.y) 
float a = acos((redLine.x * yellowLine.x + redLine.y * yellowLine.y) / lengthRedLine / lengthYellowLine)
```